# Should someone design a logo/banner for the Computer Graphics Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Something that came to my mind recently was: would it be a good idea if someone would **design a logo/banner for this website like other stack exchanges have?** For example [**gamedev.com**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). 
[image]

It makes the site look a lot nicer to use rather than the current one. If it is possible where would someone submit a design and find the design guidelines? It would make sense to do it since the site seems to be growing every day with new questions and users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At present Computer Graphics Stack Exchange is in Public Beta.

New Stack Exchange sites start out as proposed sites on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). If successful there, they go on to have a Private Beta for a week or two. If at the end of that time they are considered ready, they move on to Public Beta, where anyone can join up and contribute. This is the stage we are currently at.

Eventually, a site can graduate to become a full Stack Exchange site. This means removal of the Beta label, and a number of other changes. One of these changes is a professional design for the site (as shown in your question).

The criteria for graduation have changed over time, but currently the rough guideline is that [a site will be considered for graduation when it has 10 questions per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). This isn't a strict rule, but currently we have 2 questions per day, so it may be a while before we are ready to graduate.

Comment: Yes. In the mean time, let's fantasize about a future where cg.se has a  nice banner with refracting/reflecting glass spheres, like those screenshots in the [MDL page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/material-definition-language.html) :)